# Extract features for tag prediction project

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, svm, text-mining

I am thinking of doing a project for keyword extraction of stack exchange questions in python.
I have an input data from kaggle.com which has id,title,body and  tags for training.
I am thinking of implementing some machine learning algorithms like SVM,neural networks etc to train classifiers.
The problem is for input to these algorithms we need features.
And i dont have idea how to extract features from this input for these algorithms as i have never extracted features from a paragraph before.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Basic features for text are *terms* (roughly single words). But you might also consider other factors such as term frequency, etc.  (check [Features for text](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/features-for-text-1.html) keeping in mind that *feature engineering* is one of the key issues in machine learning). Scikit-learn has built-in [feature extraction functions for text](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction). A more specific question once you've implemented something will be better suited for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Feature selection is of crucial importance,it gives information of the relevance of features for your problem.Good theoretical explanation is given in Pattern Recognition by Sergios Theodoridis and Konstantinos Koutroumbas book.
I found this simple code example

```
# Feature Importance
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
# load the iris datasets
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
# fit an Extra Trees model to the data
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
# display the relative importance of each attribute
print(model.feature_importances_)
```

Result

```
0.1087327   0.06409384  0.32304493  0.50412853
```

You can read more [http://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-in-python-with-scikit-learn/],with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the keyword extraction algorithms are based on classical statistical techniques (including graphical models). The popular feature are mostly frequency based. Some algorithms of ranking words also exist.
For further study, consider this paper:

> http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/~saidul/acl14.pdf